# Coloring different rows of a table using jquery based on condition in the table rows itself

Tags: jquery

I am working on improving the visual appeal of table rows. The data in table rows is generated dynamically and has lots of information. There is a column in that table which gives the time when that particular information row was issued. On the basis of the days/months etc before which the information was issued, I have to color the different rows.

It's exactly like as shown in the following link :
http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm

Moreover, the table rows must also have a small colored bar,the color of which will be determined by another field in the same row.I am wondering how to go about it in jquery. I know javascript but its getting messed up.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. you can change the background color of a table cell depending on the value (table cell value less then zero):

```
// for each table cell
$('td').each(function() {
    // get table cell value and try to convert to an float
    var fValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
    // if value is a number and less then zero
    if (!isNaN(fValue) && fValue < 0) {
        // change the background color to red
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

The script has to be called after the table is built. Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pk3tB/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

To get the row of the cell, you can use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
// for each table cell
$('td').each(function() {
    // get table cell value and try to convert to an float
    var fValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
    // if value is a number and less then zero
    if (!isNaN(fValue) && fValue < 0) {
        // get table row
        var oTableRow = $(this).parent();
        // change the background color to red
        oTableRow.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pk3tB/2/).

---

Next alternative is to walk over all `tr`s:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var jRow = $(this);
    // for each table cell
    jRow.find('td').each(function() {
        // get table cell value and try to convert to an float
        var fValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
        // if value is a number and less then zero
        if (!isNaN(fValue) && fValue < 0) {
            // change the background color of the row to red
            jRow.css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pk3tB/3/).

---

To use the `.find("td.<selector>")` the `<selector>` has to be a class of the `td`. Alternative you can use `.find("td[attr='..']")` to filter all `td`s with a special attribute. But I don't know a selector for content.

Comment: The question carries on rows... I suggest to loop over `tr` rather than `td` and to access to the cell with the condition value with a `find("td.<selector>")`...

Comment: Great! That's a detailed answer :-) I think the last solution is the closest from what has been asked...

Comment: Thanky, I wish you great success.